# add text color and background jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

ohh, i have big problem with somethings easy. :(

this is jquery validate with modals, but the text error cannot change the color. i have been tried in css, but nothing happend.

```js
function showModals() {
   $("#myModals").modal("show");
  }

 //validasi password
                                                $("form#formUsr").validate({
                                                    errorClass: "my-error-class",
                                                    validClass: "my-valid-class",
                                                    rules: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            equalTo: "#password_baru",
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    messages: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!"
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!",
                                                            equalTo: "Password tidak sama!"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
```

```css
my-error-class {
    color:red!important;
}
my-valid-class {
    color:green!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="showModals(this.id);" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Profil</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModals" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah User</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="formUsr">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password Baru</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="password_baru" class="form-control" name="password_baru" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Minimal 6 karakter">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ulangi Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="ulangi_password" class="form-control" name="ulangi_password" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ulangi password baru">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                  
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                                    <input id="submit" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-flat pull-right" value="Simpan">
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

how to change color and background color error messagess ?thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Class** should always be prepended with a period (.), Check the CSS for the change.

```js
function showModals() {
   $("#myModals").modal("show");
  }

 //validasi password
                                                $("form#formUsr").validate({
                                                    errorClass: "my-error-class",
                                                    validClass: "my-valid-class",
                                                    rules: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            equalTo: "#password_baru",
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    messages: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!"
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!",
                                                            equalTo: "Password tidak sama!"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
```

```css
.my-error-class {
    color:red!important;
}
.my-valid-class {
    color:green!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="showModals(this.id);" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Profil</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModals" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah User</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="formUsr">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password Baru</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="password_baru" class="form-control" name="password_baru" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Minimal 6 karakter">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ulangi Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="ulangi_password" class="form-control" name="ulangi_password" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ulangi password baru">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                  
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                                    <input id="submit" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-flat pull-right" value="Simpan">
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed dot in CSS class, You've to define class with dot (.) in CSS like this `.my-error-class`

```js
function showModals() {
   $("#myModals").modal("show");
  }

 //validasi password
                                                $("form#formUsr").validate({
                                                    errorClass: "my-error-class",
                                                    validClass: "my-valid-class",
                                                    rules: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            equalTo: "#password_baru",
                                                            minlength: 6
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    messages: {
                                                        password_baru: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!"
                                                        },
                                                        ulangi_password: {
                                                            minlength: "Password minimal 6 karakter!",
                                                            equalTo: "Password tidak sama!"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
```

```css
.my-error-class {
    color:red!important;
}
.my-valid-class {
    color:green!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="showModals(this.id);" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Profil</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModals" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah User</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="formUsr">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password Baru</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="password_baru" class="form-control" name="password_baru" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Minimal 6 karakter">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ulangi Password</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <input type="password" id="ulangi_password" class="form-control" name="ulangi_password" required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ulangi password baru">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                  
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                                    <input id="submit" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-flat pull-right" value="Simpan">
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The same answer is already below. Please check the answers once.